# Delete item after a date (Firebase Cloud function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a firebase cloud function to delete automatically an event after is date is passed.

Based on this example [Firebase example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/delete-old-child-nodes/functions/index.js), I came to this, but when I'm uploading it on Firebase, it is running on Firebase side but it is not deleting events.

Do you guys have advices or see something wrong in my code ? Is it possible that the problem may coming from the trigger `onWrite()` ?

```js
/* My database structure

   /events
                item1: {
                    MyTimestamp: 1497911193083
                },
                item2: {
                    MyTimestamp: 1597911193083                    
                }
                ...
*/


// Cloud function to delete events after the date is passed

'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/events/{eventId}').onWrite((change) => {
  
  const ref = change.after.ref.parent; // reference to the parent
  const now = Date.now();
  const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('MyTimestamp').endAt(now);

  return oldItemsQuery.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    // create a map with all children that need to be removed
    const updates = {};
     snapshot.forEach(child => {
        updates[child.key] = null;
     });
    return ref.update(updates);
    // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
  });
});
```

Comment: Which versions of the `firebase-functions` and `firebase-admin` packages are you using? Are there any errors in the cloud function logs?

Comment: No, i don't have any errors, my function is running.

Comment: Hello Memphis, were you able to solve this problem? I'm facing same problem now

Comment: Sorry for the delay @olajide, I hadn't a notification from Stackoverflow... The solution I came with was to use Cron Job to manage the delete of my records. https://cron-job.org/en/

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the code, just update you cloud functions & admin:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref("/events/{eventId}").onWrite((change, context) => {
  if (change.after.exists() && !change.before.exists()) {
    const ref = change.after.ref.parent;
    const now = Date.now();
    const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('MyTimestamp').endAt(now);
    return oldItemsQuery.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      const updates = {};
      snapshot.forEach(child => {
        updates[child.key] = null;
      });
      return ref.update(updates);
    });
  } else {
    return null;
  }
});
```

Run the following in the functions folder:

`npm install firebase-functions@latest --save 
npm install firebase-admin@5.11.0 --save`

Reference [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff) for more details

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i tried it and now the function is triggered, but all the time ! Whatever the `Date.now()` or `timestamps` compared... Each new record is deleted.

Comment: When do you want the function to be triggered?

Comment: I have updated the function to be executed only when new events are added. Please test and let me know if its working as expected

Comment: Thanks a lot to helping me ! I would like the function is triggered when an event (his `timestamps`) become older than the `Date.now()` date. I would like the function acte like a watchdog, when an event is ended, it is automatically deleted.

Comment: Basically, when in `item 1`, `MyTimestamp: 1497911193083` is older than `Date.now()`, `item 1` is deleted.

Comment: @Memphis I think You need CRON to schedule Your function to be called every X minutes. I don't know if Firebase supports this. Did You solve Your issue? I'm planning my app and I will also need such functionality, so any hint will help :)

Comment: @Memphis take a look at https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html

Comment: How can this be done in firestore? is it similar code?

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
 admin.initializeApp();
```

to :

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Comment: Indeed, to trigger the function, it worked better with `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)`, but I have a new problem now, the function is deleting all new records...

Comment: @Memphis Because interval is  'now'  `.endAt(now)` .  Check the Firebase example again.